# Rails 4.2 managing multiple columns with same enum values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, enums

I have a use case where I want to have 2 columns with same enum array. Below is the sample code I am trying to implement. Initially got error with below code, then added suffix ad prefix.

```
class Sample
  enum status1: {initiated: 1, ringing: 2}, _suffix: true
  enum status2: {initiated: 1, ringing: 2}, _prefix: :stat2
end
```

Now when I try to access the model from rails console to assign values to status1 or status2 using below code, I get error

```
s = Sample.last
```

NoMethodError: undefined method `each_with_index' for true:TrueClass

So here I want to have mulitple columns with same enum values and to be able to assign values to them and save.

Comment: Which version of rails are you using, because I think prefix and suffix is only available in rails 5

Comment: I am using rails 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4.2 does not support the use of _prefix and _suffix. This is a feature introduced with Rails 5. You can see [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/09bef7684a5ddd0e37d8bed38858a9fa866e1df2) the commit to the rails master branch that introduces the feature.

You will either have to implement the new rails 5 version of enum or just manually prefix or suffix them to prevent name clashes. Rails generates methods for the model based on the enum values it declares, so that is why two identically named enum values cannot have the same name.